# Alignment of Rhandsontable's row names in Shiny

Tags: shiny, alignment, rhandsontable, r-rownames

Is there a way to **align** the **row names** of a **Rhandsontable** in a Shiny app? I only found an argument to adjust the width (`rowHeaderWidth`), but not the alignment of the row names separately from the body of the table that I know can be done with `hot_col()`. If it's not possible using the `rhandsontable()` function, what should the CSS code be?

Simple Shiny example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table')
  
)

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(mtcars, rowHeaderWidth = 200)
  })
  
  
}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot_01]

[image: screenshot_02]

If you see screenshot 01 from browser inspection that you need to change text-align.
you can create style.css file and link the file in app (see screenshot 02)

Comment: See above a simple code example :)